# jquery click vs button executed function to find length of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I am currently working with a JQuery function that determines if there are any checkboxes checked in my form.  I'm using JQuery v1.10.2

This code works fine whenever I execute it with a button, but when I try to use a checkbox within the form to execute it, it does nothing.  I've tested with a JFiddle, and that worked, but in my form, the alert does not fire.  I've checked for redundant names, and my form id is unique.  Could it be the div/table structures within the form causing some sort of conflict?  The form is wrapped inside of a hidden div.  Thanks for any help.

Below is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$(".ksa_button_check").click(function(){
    $(".ksa_check_k, .ksa_check_s").click(function(){

        if ($("#ksaChecks input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
            alert('is checked');
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: HTML might also be helpful

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Comment: Not sure I get it, you have a form with a checkbox, wrapped inside a hidden div, so how do you change the checkbox ?

Comment: Thanks.  The div is hidden onload and becomes visible once the user clicks on the link.  No errors in the console.  Working on getting the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
checkboxes.click(function() {
    alert("Checkbox Is Checked");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/aTDj6/1/

Not sure which language you are using. If you are using PHP you could check if $_POST has a value etc. If a checkbox is checked it would have $_POST data if not it would not.

Something like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$checkboxes = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : array();
foreach($checkboxes as $value) {
Do something
);
};
};
```

Other than that I am wondering if your checkboxes are losing its state on your form submit. So yea as others said would help to see the code.